# Ordering on specific column not working - jquery Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a problem on my last column (**column index 15**) reordering on my datatable. Even when no disabled ordering on that column is declared, I can't seem to order it programmatically, yet even manually. My other columns are ordering just fine.

```
 <table id="tblRequestLoaLedger" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed w-100">
     <thead class="table-info text-center justify-content-center">
         <tr>
             <th scope="col" class="pl-1 pr-1">Options</th>
             <th scope="col" class="pl-1 pr-1">Issue LOA</th>
             <th scope="col" class="pl-1 pr-1">Discussions</th>
             <th scope="col">Request No.</th>
             <th scope="col">Date Requested</th>
             <th scope="col">Date Availed</th>
             <th scope="col">Member ID</th>
             <th scope="col">Member Name</th>
             <th scope="col">Hospital | Clinic</th>
             <th scope="col">Account Name</th>
             <th scope="col">Status</th>
             <th scope="col">LOA No.</th>
             <th scope="col">Approved Amount</th>
             <th scope="col">Reason</th>
             <th scope="col">LOA Code</th>
             <th scope="col">Has New Msgs</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr role="row" class="odd">
              <td class="text-center">
                  <div class="dropdown">
                      <button class="btn btn btn-outline-info btn-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-ellipsis" type="button" id="dropdownRLoaOpt" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
                      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="GetImages(4579);">View Images</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="GetMemberProfile(64378);">View Member's Profile</a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </td>
              <td scope="row" class="text-center">
                  <a class="btn btn btn-outline-info btn-circle" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="GetLOAAvailmentDetails(4579);">
                      <i class="fa fa-file" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </a>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center" data-order="0">
                  <a class="btn btn btn-outline-info btn-circle" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="GetMsgsRequestLOA(4579, 64378, 'ADVENTO, NANETH', this);">
                      <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
                      <span class="badge badge-danger ml-1"></span>
                  </a>
              </td>
              <td class="">04579</td>
              <td class="text-center">09/06/2018</td>
              <td class="text-center">09/06/2018</td>
              <td class="text-right">86761-00</td>
              <td class="text-nowrap">ADVENTO, NANETH</td>
              <td class="text-nowrap">A. ZARATE GENERAL HOSPITAL</td>
              <td class="text-nowrap">ACCONA GENERAL MERCHANDISE</td>
              <td class="text-center align-middle"><span class="badge badge-secondary">CANCELLED</span></td>
              <td></td>
              <td class="text-right">0.00</td>
              <td></td>
              <td>4580</td>
              <td class="sorting_1">0</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    InitTblRequestLoa();
    TblRequestLoaActions();

    $('#aNewMsgs').on('click', function () {
        $('#fDateReq').val('');
        $('#fDateReqTo').val('');
        InitTblRequestLoa().order([15, 'desc']).draw();
    });
});

function InitTblRequestLoa() {
    return $('#tblRequestLoaLedger').DataTable({
        retrieve: true,
        dom: "<'row'<'col-12't>>" +
            "<'row'<'col-6'i><'col-6'l>>" +
            "<'row'<'col-12'p>>",
        order: [[3, 'desc']],
        language: {
            emptyTable: 'No data available'
        },
        columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: [0, 1, 2],
                orderable: false

            },
            {
                targets: [14],
                visible: false
            },
            {
                targets: [15],
                type: 'num'
            }
        ]
        ,
        stateSave: true,
        stateSaveCallback: function (settings, data) {
            var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);
            localStorage.setItem(api.table().node().id, JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        stateLoadCallback: function (settings, callback) {
            var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);
            try {
                return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(api.table().node().id));
            } catch (e) { }
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see, I have tried specifying the column type as `num`, and still no luck. Any solutions to this?

---

### SOLVED

DataTables had trouble ordering `Has Msgs` column because I was trying to assign a data to a cell using this line:

`$(thisRow).find('td:nth-child(15)').html("1");`

Turns out DataTables doesn't recognize that assignment and I had to 'really' assign the data via the DataTables api, [cell.data()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data()), thanks to @samabcde.

`tblRequestLoaLedger.cell(rowIndex, 15).data('1');`

Answer (score 2):

Column index starts with 0 so your last column will be 14.

Just change `columnDefs` like this

```
columnDefs: [
        {
            targets: [0, 1, 2],
            orderable: false

        },
        {
            targets: [13],
            visible: false
        },
        {
            targets: [14],
            type: 'num'
        }
    ],
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hc9x4f6b/)

Comment: Hi, @MyTwoCents!, please refer to my edited post as I have forgotten a column to include. (Sorry!)

Answer (score 1):

The index you specified in `targets` of `columnDefs` is not correct, since you have 15 columns, and the index start at 0, the index for 15th column should be 14. This cause the following js error:

> TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined.

Which then make the ordering not working. After fixing this problem, the table ordering should be fine.

Check this [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/340de1wv/2/) for a working table.

Comment: Hi, @samabcde! Thank you for your solution. Unfortunately, I seemed to forgot to include the `LOA Code` column (not visible), so there should be really 16 columns. And `Has New Msgs` column is still index 15 as well. Still not working though. I corrected and formatted my question. Sorry for this. Can you please look into it again?

Comment: No problem is found after adding the column and change back the index. Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/340de1wv/5/).

Comment: I have checked the fiddle, and yeah, it seems to be working fine. I am so confused as to what has gone wrong with my code. Do you have any idea where did I somehow go wrong?

Comment: You may try to create a fiddle that reproduce the problem. It seems that the problem may be related to other part of your code, which you did not cover in the question.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to create one. But first, I want to let you know that the `Has Msgs` column content has only two values either this default: `<td>0</td>` or is generated dynamically by a condition like this : `$(thisRow).find('td:nth-child(15)').html("1");`

Do these lines affect the ordering of the table?

Comment: I think this really matter, you need to change the `data` of datatable also instead of changing the html only. See [cell.data()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data()) for details.

Comment: Seriously, that was it! It worked! I really had to change the cell's data! This was very helpful, sir! Thank you very much! :)